# Can anyone point me in the direction of a GOOD java functions/objects/methods tut?

Tags: java, object, methods

Im having difficulties understanding how to split my program up into smaller functions instead of a cluster of code in the main function. Yes, I have looked for a guide on my own. The ones that I found either didn't help or further confused me. Thanks :)

Edit: 
I come from a very limited C++ and JavaScript background.

In C++ I could simply do this:

```
int main () {
int x,y;

cin >> x >> y;
cout << addNum(x,y) << endl;
}

int addNum(num1,num2) {
return num1+num2;
}
```

Im so lost in java. :S

Comment: Well, first of all which ones didn't help you? It would help to list them and explain why they didn't help.

Comment: [Oracle Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Uncle Bob - [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882).

Comment: ^^^ That one definitely didn't help. Ill edit my post to be more descriptive.

Comment: [Clean code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/0132350882) is a very good reference.

Comment: @assylias It in fact is a good reference, but for a bloody beginner it might be a little bit over the top. OP should state something about his experience and education in software engineering.

Comment: @Fildor I don't remember that it was very technical.

Comment: @assylias I guess the OP is in need of some more concrete help. Like in the form of "if x,y,z, then make it a class, if a,b or c then make it a method ... " The real basics.

Comment: @Fildor based on the edit it seems you are right!

Comment: :3 Yeah. Im having issues grasping the basics. We all start somewhere right? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @MK3GTX that's not valid C++ code in your edit. I have linked the Methods section of the Oracle Java Tutorial above, but you can just start at the beginning of the tutorial. It teaches you the basics in a pretty straight forward way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should read into "Object Oriented Programming" (not a book title, but something to search for ...) first.

Another good start would be "Design Patterns" but after you got familiar with the basics of OOP.

Some references on OOP:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/
- http://www.aonaware.com/OOP1.htm

... on design patterns:

- http://www.oodesign.com/

Answer (score 1):

A suggest you start simple and your your IDE to refactor out methods.  Having unit tests and re-writing your code to make it clearer and simpler can iteratively improve your code.

In Java you could write your example with.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scanner.nextInt(), y = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(addNum(x, y));
    }

    private static int addNum(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

While Java is verbose, the IDE can help you write most of it so you don't have to type that much more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are from c++ background, I guess you missed that functions have to be part of a class (one could say everything is an object in java).

```
class Math{
    int add(int x, int y){
     return x + y;
    }
}
```

You then create an instance of Math and call add() on that instance. You can also make the add() function static to avoid creating an instance

For example, within the main method

```
Math m = new Math();
System.out.println(m.add(x,y));
```

if add() was a static function, you would code

```
System.out.println(Math.add(x,y));
```

As suggested by many others, it is best that you go read some good books on OOPs and Java. I would recommend ***Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel. Its a good book for somebody from C++ background.***